# publicSaleKey in NFT smart contract - what's the use?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, solidity-0.8.x

In the Azuki NFT smart contract, the public mint function requires a `publicSaleKey` to be sent with it:

```
    function publicSaleMint(
        uint256 quantity,
        uint256 callerPublicSaleKey
    ) external payable callerIsUser {
        SaleConfig memory config = saleConfig;
        uint256 publicSaleKey = uint256(config.publicSaleKey);
        uint256 publicPrice = uint256(config.publicPrice);
        uint256 publicSaleStartTime = uint256(config.publicSaleStartTime);
        require(
            publicSaleKey == callerPublicSaleKey,
            "called with incorrect public sale key"
        );
        require(
            _isPublicSaleOn(publicPrice, publicSaleKey, publicSaleStartTime),
            "public sale has not begun yet"
        );
        require(
            totalSupply() + quantity <= collectionSize,
            "reached max supply"
        );
        require(
            numberMinted(msg.sender) + quantity <= maxPerAddressDuringMint,
            "can not mint this many"
        );
        _safeMint(msg.sender, quantity);
        _addFunder();
        _refundIfOver(publicPrice * quantity);
    }
```

What purpose does this serve?

The public sale key is stored in a public struct and queryable at any time.
Anyone could include it in a transaction.

Confused as to why it was added, would appreciate any insights as I'm coopting this contract to use in a project of my own.